# Fatal error: Call to undefined function mssql_query()

Tags: php, sql-server

Having this error when trying to query an INSERT, I have to to run when a Submit button is clicked.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['newPartbtn'])){
  $result = mssql_query("INSERT INTO Parts (PartNumber) VALUES ('2222')");
  if($result)
  {
    echo "Success";
  }
  else
  {
    echo "Error";
  }
}
?>
```

New to PHP so sorry if this is basic!

Here is my code to connect,

```
<?php
  $serverName = "Server";

  $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"Database");
  $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

  if( $conn ) {
       echo "Connection established.<br />";
  }else{
       echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
       die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
  }
  ?>
```

Comment: Hi did you connect to your database. I dont see any code for doing that in this snippet

Comment: If you're using php 7, that function has been removed. See [here](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-query.php).

Comment: @RiggsFolly would a missing connection explain `mssql_query` being undefined?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Maybe not. your option looks more likely

Comment: I think You have not the MS SQL Drivers installed. You can check this with phpinfo();

Comment: @AjayKadoula looks like I don't have the drivers Installed

Comment: Where could I get these drivers as the MS Download centre seems to have removed it?

Answer (score 0):

First call for a new connection

```
      <?php
      if(isset($_POST['newPartbtn'])){
      $conn = mssql_connect('KALLESPC\SQLEXPRESS', 'sa', 'phpfi');
      $sql = mssql_query("INSERT INTO Parts (PartNumber) VALUES ('2222')");
      if($result)
      {
      echo "Success";
      }
      else
       {
       echo "Error";
       }
       }
       ?>
```

Comment: That solves the wrong function, however, I doubt it'll solve the problem here; that the function is undefined (probably) as it doesn't exist in their installation of php.

Comment: Yeah, not existing in php 7.0 or +